# How to implement Rope data structure split operation

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

I was reading about Rope(or cord) data structure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure) and trying to implement it, but I am struggling to implement the split operation. I tried to look it up but all related answers I was able to find were incorrect.

Below is the split operation:

[image]

We want to find the character and return two nodes before and after the split. For example, if we want to split at index 5 of'MyNameIsSimon' then we should return the root of two ropes 'MyName' and 'IsSimon' respectively. Finding the index is easy as given by the pseudo-code in wiki. But I'm struggling the split part especially how to join and return the 2nd half as a new rope. Anyone can help with pseudo-code or any language is much appreciated.

Comment: The second part is easy.  You have K and H, and you join them by creating a new node with K as the left, H as the right, and the length of K as its weight.

Comment: I know how to join two nodes together, the question is basically how to recursively implement split with join, like how to find all nodes we need to discard and join them on the way of searching the index.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia’s diagram looks muddled to me. Here’s a working implementation in Python (without balancing).

```
class Leaf:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self._s = s

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._s)

    def __str__(self):
        return self._s

    def inspect(self, indent=0):
        print(" " * indent + repr(self._s))

    def split(self, i):
        return Leaf(self._s[:i]), Leaf(self._s[i:])


class Branch:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._l = len(a) + len(b)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._l

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._a) + str(self._b)

    def inspect(self, indent=0):
        self._a.inspect(indent + 2)
        print(" " * indent + str(len(self._a)))
        self._b.inspect(indent + 2)

    def split(self, i):
        if i < len(self._a):
            a0, a1 = self._a.split(i)
            return a0, Branch(a1, self._b)
        elif i == len(self._a):
            return self._a, self._b
        else:
            assert i > len(self._a)
            b0, b1 = self._b.split(i - len(self._a))
            return Branch(self._a, b0), b1


def make_test_rope():
    e = Leaf("Hello ")
    f = Leaf("my ")
    c = Branch(e, f)
    j = Leaf("na")
    k = Leaf("me i")
    g = Branch(j, k)
    m = Leaf("s")
    n = Leaf(" Simon")
    h = Branch(m, n)
    d = Branch(g, h)
    b = Branch(c, d)
    a = Branch(b, Leaf(""))
    return a


def test():
    a = make_test_rope()
    a.inspect()
    b, c = a.split(11)
    print("--")
    b.inspect()
    print("--")
    c.inspect()


test()
```

Output:

```py
      'Hello '
    6
      'my '
  9
        'na'
      2
        'me i'
    6
        's'
      1
        ' Simon'
22
  ''
--
    'Hello '
  6
    'my '
9
  'na'
--
    'me i'
  4
      's'
    1
      ' Simon'
11
  ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a rope as “borrowing” the balancing algorithm of a binary search tree. Each leaf node represents an actual piece of text, with internal nodes representing concatenations. We then look at just the internal nodes in the tree and use a classical tree-balancing algorithm to keep those nodes in the shape of a balanced BST.

Your question then boils down to the following: how do you efficiently perform a split operation on a BST? The good news is that there are lots of different types of balanced BSTs that support fast splitting. The easiest of these is splay trees - you can split a splay tree by splaying the smallest value above the split point, then cutting one of its child links. Other BSTs can be split as well, but the algorithms are more complex. Red/black trees can be split and joined together, but the algorithms involved are a bit messy, for example.